# Python concurrent.futures global variables

Tags: python, global-variables, concurrent.futures

I have a multiprocessing code, and each process have to analyse same data differently.
The input data is always the same, it is not changeable.
Input data is a data frame 20 columns and 60k rows.

How to efficiently 'put' this data to each process?

On single process application I have used global variable, but in multiprocessing it's not working.

When I try to transfer this as a function argument, I have only the first element of the table

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to take the time and give reproducible minimal working examples to get specific answers and help the society in general.

Anyway, you shouldn't use global variables if you need to change them with each iteration/process/etc.

Multiprocessing works like that in rough easily-digestible terms:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import glob

def manipulate_data_function(data):
    result = torture_data(data)
    return result

# ProcessPoolExecutor for CPU bound stuff
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = None) as executor:
    futures = []
    for file in glob.glob('*txt'):
        futures.append(executor.submit(manipulate_data_function, data))
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer, I don't change this date each iteration. I use the same data to each process, data how to change the data is given throw function argument

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
   res = executor.map(goal_fcn, p)

for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(res):
   fp = res
```

and next

```
def goal_fcn(x):
   return heavy_calculation(x, global_DataFrame, global_String)
```

**EDIT:**
it work with:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
   res = executor.map(goal_fcn, p, [global_DataFrame], [global_String])

for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(res):
   fp = res
```

```
def goal_fcn(x, DataFrame, String):
   return heavy_calculation(x, DataFrame, String)
```